# how to make push elements from two different arrays with same appName inside a new Array in javascript

Tags: javascript, arrays, conditional-statements

These are two arrays having some data

```
var z = [
  {
    appId: "1",
    appName: "CapLogix",
    envId: "970",
    envName: "UAT4"
  },
  {
    appId: "1",
    appName: "CapLogix",
    envId: "970",
    envName: "UAT4"
  },
  {
    appId: "1",
    appName: "CapLogix",
    envId: "970",
    envName: "UAT4"
  },
  {
    appId: "21",
    appName: "NOCC",
    envId: "967",
    envName: "UAT4"
  },
  {
    appId: "21",
    appName: "NOCC",
    envId: "967",
    envName: "UAT4"
  },
  {
    appId: "21",
    appName: "NOCC",
    envId: "967",
    envName: "UAT4"
  },
  {
    appId: "71",
    appName: "NETLOGIX",
    envId: "972",
    envName: "UAT4"
  },
  {
    appId: "71",
    appName: "NETLOGIX",
    envId: "972",
    envName: "UAT4"
  },
  {
    appId: "71",
    appName: "NETLOGIX",
    envId: "972",
    envName: "UAT4"
  },
  {
    appId: "73",
    appName: "ConfigBuilder",
    envId: "971",
    envName: "UAT4"
  },
  {
    appId: "73",
    appName: "ConfigBuilder",
    envId: "971",
    envName: "UAT4"
  }
];

var y = [
  {
    appId: "1",
    appName: "CapLogix",
    envId: "959",
    envName: "SIT-4"
  },
  {
    appId: "1",
    appName: "CapLogix",
    envId: "959",
    envName: "SIT-4"
  },
  {
    appId: "21",
    appName: "NOCC",
    envId: "965",
    envName: "SIT-4"
  },
  {
    appId: "21",
    appName: "NOCC",
    envId: "965",
    envName: "SIT-4"
  },
  {
    appId: "71",
    appName: "NETLOGIX",
    envId: "958",
    envName: "SIT-4"
  },
  {
    appId: "71",
    appName: "NETLOGIX",
    envId: "958",
    envName: "SIT-4"
  },
  {
    appId: "73",
    appName: "ConfigBuilder",
    envId: "963",
    envName: "SIT-4"
  },
  {
    appId: "73",
    appName: "ConfigBuilder",
    envId: "963",
    envName: "SIT-4"
  }
];
```

This is what I have tried so far.i need a new array with the elements having same appName from above two arrays into a new array.

```js
var z = [{
    appId: "1",
    appName: "CapLogix",
    envId: "970",
    envName: "UAT4"
  },
  {
    appId: "1",
    appName: "CapLogix",
    envId: "970",
    envName: "UAT4"
  },
  {
    appId: "1",
    appName: "CapLogix",
    envId: "970",
    envName: "UAT4"
  },
  {
    appId: "21",
    appName: "NOCC",
    envId: "967",
    envName: "UAT4"
  },
  {
    appId: "21",
    appName: "NOCC",
    envId: "967",
    envName: "UAT4"
  },
  {
    appId: "21",
    appName: "NOCC",
    envId: "967",
    envName: "UAT4"
  },
  {
    appId: "71",
    appName: "NETLOGIX",
    envId: "972",
    envName: "UAT4"
  },
  {
    appId: "71",
    appName: "NETLOGIX",
    envId: "972",
    envName: "UAT4"
  },
  {
    appId: "71",
    appName: "NETLOGIX",
    envId: "972",
    envName: "UAT4"
  },
  {
    appId: "73",
    appName: "ConfigBuilder",
    envId: "971",
    envName: "UAT4"
  },
  {
    appId: "73",
    appName: "ConfigBuilder",
    envId: "971",
    envName: "UAT4"
  }
];

var y = [{
    appId: "1",
    appName: "CapLogix",
    envId: "959",
    envName: "SIT-4"
  },
  {
    appId: "1",
    appName: "CapLogix",
    envId: "959",
    envName: "SIT-4"
  },
  {
    appId: "21",
    appName: "NOCC",
    envId: "965",
    envName: "SIT-4"
  },
  {
    appId: "21",
    appName: "NOCC",
    envId: "965",
    envName: "SIT-4"
  },
  {
    appId: "71",
    appName: "NETLOGIX",
    envId: "958",
    envName: "SIT-4"
  },
  {
    appId: "71",
    appName: "NETLOGIX",
    envId: "958",
    envName: "SIT-4"
  },
  {
    appId: "73",
    appName: "ConfigBuilder",
    envId: "963",
    envName: "SIT-4"
  },
  {
    appId: "73",
    appName: "ConfigBuilder",
    envId: "963",
    envName: "SIT-4"
  }
];




for (var i in z) {
  if (z[i].appName == "NOCC") {
    document.getElementById("sa").innerHTML += "{" + "<br>" + "appId  :" + z[i].appId + "<br>" + " appName  : " + z[i].appName + "<br>" + "envId  :" + z[i].envId + "<br>" + " envName  : " + z[i].envName + "<br>" + "}" + "<br>" + "," + "</br>";
  }
}

for (var i in y) {
  if (y[i].appName == "NOCC") {
    document.getElementById("as").innerHTML += "{" + "<br>" + "appId  :" + y[i].appId + "<br>" + " appName  : " + y[i].appName + "<br>" + "envId  :" + y[i].envId + "<br>" + " envName  : " + y[i].envName + "<br>" + "}" + "<br>" + "," + "</br>";
  }
}
```

```html
<div id='sa'></div>
<div id='as'></div>
```

Comment: Convert code into a [mcve] by clicking the bracket button `[<>]`

Comment: Your motive is not clear what you are trying to do.

Comment: i need the elements having same "appName" from above two arrays into a new array example in above problem ,there is a attribute "appName :"= "CapLogix" in both arrays z,y. but i to print the elements from both of the arrays having same appName into a new array .i hope you get me @Mridul

Comment: I had posted a complete solution...unfortunately you didn't post a [mcve] so I deleted it...good luck.

Comment: @zer00ne bro actually i am new here i didnt know to convert it to minimal reproducible example . i am really sorry for that. but can you post solution.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

- Use [`.concat()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/concat) to combine both arrays.

  ```
  z.concat(y)
  ```
- Use [`.reduce()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/reduce) to group all objects with matching `appName` values in their own separate arrays. In order to keep each array name, they should all be returned inside a single object literal.

  ```
  // result pattern
  {
    "CapLogix": [{
      "appId": "1",
      "appName": "CapLogix",
      "envId": "970",
      "envName": "UAT4"
  }, {...}],...}
  ```
- Use 3 [`for...of` loops](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Statements/for...of) to render with [`.insertAdjacentHTML()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Element/insertAdjacentHTML):

  1. a `<dt>` for each array name ex.`<hr><dt>CapLogix</dt><hr>`
  2. a `<hr>` for every object
  3. a `<dd>` for every key/value pair ex. `<dd>"envName": "UAT4"</dd>`
- [`Object.entries()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Object/entries) was used to convert object literals into array of arrays

```js
var z=[{appId:"1",appName:"CapLogix",envId:"970",envName:"UAT4"},{appId:"1",appName:"CapLogix",envId:"970",envName:"UAT4"},{appId:"1",appName:"CapLogix",envId:"970",envName:"UAT4"},{appId:"21",appName:"NOCC",envId:"967",envName:"UAT4"},{appId:"21",appName:"NOCC",envId:"967",envName:"UAT4"},{appId:"21",appName:"NOCC",envId:"967",envName:"UAT4"},{appId:"71",appName:"NETLOGIX",envId:"972",envName:"UAT4"},{appId:"71",appName:"NETLOGIX",envId:"972",envName:"UAT4"},{appId:"71",appName:"NETLOGIX",envId:"972",envName:"UAT4"},{appId:"73",appName:"ConfigBuilder",envId:"971",envName:"UAT4"},{appId:"73",appName:"ConfigBuilder",envId:"971",envName:"UAT4"}],y=[{appId:"1",appName:"CapLogix",envId:"959",envName:"SIT-4"},{appId:"1",appName:"CapLogix",envId:"959",envName:"SIT-4"},{appId:"21",appName:"NOCC",envId:"965",envName:"SIT-4"},{appId:"21",appName:"NOCC",envId:"965",envName:"SIT-4"},{appId:"71",appName:"NETLOGIX",envId:"958",envName:"SIT-4"},{appId:"71",appName:"NETLOGIX",envId:"958",envName:"SIT-4"},{appId:"73",appName:"ConfigBuilder",envId:"963",envName:"SIT-4"},{appId:"73",appName:"ConfigBuilder",envId:"963",envName:"SIT-4"}];

function groupByKV(property, objectArrayA, objectArrayB) {
  let array = objectArrayA.concat(objectArrayB);
  return array.reduce((group, current) => {
    (group[current[property]] = group[current[property]] || []).push(current);
    return group;
  }, {});
}

function domList(data, selector = 'body') {
  const main = document.querySelector(selector);
  const list = document.createElement('dl');
  main.appendChild(list);

  let pairs = Object.entries(data);
  for (let [arrayKey, array] of pairs) {
    list.insertAdjacentHTML('beforeend', `<hr><dt>${arrayKey}:</dt><hr>`);
    for (let object of array) {
      list.insertAdjacentHTML('beforeend', `<hr>`)
      for (let [key, value] of Object.entries(object)) {
        list.insertAdjacentHTML('beforeend', `<dd>${key}: ${value}</dd>`);
      }
    }
  }
}

const arrayObject = groupByKV('appName', z, y);
console.log(arrayObject);

domList(arrayObject);
```

```css
dd::after {
  content: ','
}

dd:nth-of-type(4n)::after {
  content: ''
}

.as-console-wrapper {
  width: 350px;
  min-height: 100%;
  margin-left: 45%;
}

.as-console-row.as-console-row::after,
.as-console-row-code.as-console-row-code::after {
  content:'';
  padding:0;
  margin:0;
  border:0;
  width:0;
}
```

Comment: thank you bro this one answer is best. even in the prefect order.

Answer (score 1):

Check the snippet,

This basically get values which are present in both `z` and `y`, then creates a new array. This new array is then filtered to get the unique value.

You can add the below block if you need only unique values in the new array.

```
newArray.filter((a)=> {
        var key = a.appName;
        if (!this[key]) {
            this[key] = true;
            return true;
        }
    }, Object.create(null))
```

```js
var z = [ {
    "appId": "1",
    "appName": "CapLogix",
    "envId": "970",
    "envName": "UAT4",

  },
  {
    "appId": "1",
    "appName": "CapLogix",
    "envId": "970",
    "envName": "UAT4",

  },
  {
    "appId": "1",
    "appName": "CapLogix",
    "envId": "970",
    "envName": "UAT4",

  },

  {
    "appId": "21",
    "appName": "NOCC",
    "envId": "967",
    "envName": "UAT4",

  },
  {
    "appId": "21",
    "appName": "NOCC",
    "envId": "967",
    "envName": "UAT4",

  },
  {
    "appId": "21",
    "appName": "NOCC",
    "envId": "967",
    "envName": "UAT4",

  },

  {
    "appId": "71",
    "appName": "NETLOGIX",
    "envId": "972",
    "envName": "UAT4",

  },
  {
    "appId": "71",
    "appName": "NETLOGIX",
    "envId": "972",
    "envName": "UAT4",

  },
  {
    "appId": "71",
    "appName": "NETLOGIX",
    "envId": "972",
    "envName": "UAT4",

  },


  {
    "appId": "73",
    "appName": "ConfigBuilder",
    "envId": "971",
    "envName": "UAT4",

  },
  {
    "appId": "73",
    "appName": "ConfigBuilder",
    "envId": "971",
    "envName": "UAT4",

  }
];

  var y = [{
    "appId": "1",
    "appName": "CapLogix",
    "envId": "959",
    "envName": "SIT-4", 
  },
  {
    "appId": "1",
    "appName": "CapLogix",
    "envId": "959",
    "envName": "SIT-4",

  },
  {
    "appId": "21",
    "appName": "NOCC",
    "envId": "965",
    "envName": "SIT-4",

  },
  {
    "appId": "21",
    "appName": "NOCC",
    "envId": "965",
    "envName": "SIT-4",

  },

  {
    "appId": "71",
    "appName": "NETLOGIX",
    "envId": "958",
    "envName": "SIT-4",

  },
  {
    "appId": "71",
    "appName": "NETLOGIX",
    "envId": "958",
    "envName": "SIT-4",

  },

  {
    "appId": "73",
    "appName": "ConfigBuilder",
    "envId": "963",
    "envName": "SIT-4",

  },
  {
    "appId": "73",
    "appName": "ConfigBuilder",
    "envId": "963",
    "envName": "SIT-4",

  }]
let newArray = z.filter(o1 => y.some(o2 => o1.appName === o2.appName));

let el = '';
newArray.forEach(item =>{
  el +=`<p>id:  ${item.appId}, app Name : ${item.appName}</p>`;
});
document.getElementById('new').innerHTML = el;
//console.log(newArray)
```

```html
This is the new array with same values
<div id="new"></div>
```

Comment: thanks for the answer but i need the Elements With the same appName not different. like in your output there are different appName @Akhil Aravind

Comment: @geeky these are unique app name, if we dont a filter app name will get repeated. Like `NOCC`  will be more than 2 times.

Comment: there is no issue in repeation . All i need is a new array with the element having same appName from both arrays . Also its ok if you can print elements with appName  NOCC only but i need all enteries from both arrays into new array with appName NOCC.@Akhil Aravind

Comment: perfect dude@AkhilAravind